# PHP cli error with dynamic link library

Tags: php

Got this error whilst trying to run php via cli:

> The procedure entry point zend_replace_error_handling could not be located in the dynamic link library php5.dll

I've got no references to `zend_replace_error_handling` in my `php.ini` file.

Does anyone have an idea as to what is causing this issue?

Comment: `zend_replace_error_handling` will be an internal C function (probably). I'd try downloading a fresh copy of PHP / WAMP / XAMPP / whatever. Alternatively, there's my favourite local development option; [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/)

Comment: Vagrant looks interesting... can it port to Heroku or AWS?

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to explain what *"port to Heroku or AWS"* means. Vagrant just provides a virtualised environment that's easy to set up and tear down. The code still resides on your local disk so any tools you have can still be used. There's plenty of LAMP boxes around so the amount of work is really minimal